# quartz.net and using Dbcontext simultaneously problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, dbcontext, quartz.net

First of all, let me state that I am coding as an amateur. I don't have much technical knowledge.

In the Aspnet (.net framework) MVC project I am working on, I am using quartz.net to schedule a long running process and run it in the background.
The job running in the background is using Dbcontext and accessing the database. If I don't do anything else when the job starts running, it's fine. The job runs and finishes as I planned.

However, when my scheduled job starts running in the background, if I do other operations (requiring database access) I get the following error:

```
   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

I realized that Dbcontext is not thread-safe but I couldn't figure out how to get around this.

I think it shouldn't be too hard, it has an easy solution.

Can't I access the database on the frontend when a job is running in the background that uses the Dbcontext? (Let me remind you, I don't have much technical knowledge, maybe there is a really simple solution.)

Comment: Hi ibrahim. Is there any more information you can give? For example, a stack trace when the error occurs? Or maybe there is an "InnerException" inside of your current exception? "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityExceptoin" is not a lot to work with.

Comment: I am not familiar with DbContext, but googling a little bit strengthens my suspicion that you are using DbContext the wrong way. It is probably a lightweight object that is supposed to have a short lifetime, often just for a single query. So your solution is likely to just create several DbContext wherever you need them.

Comment: Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: First of all thanks both of you. I was following a course while writing code. And in that course for creating Dbcontext was using singleton pattern. After searching i saw that it is wrong for multi thread applications. That's why I was encountering this error.